# Setting cmake var on command line vs in CMakeLists

Tags: cmake

The following works when I run from the command line, and the generated Xcode project has the architecture set to what I have passed here:

`cmake ../src/ -GXcode -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="armv7 arm64"`

I thought I would instead put this information into CMakeLists like so:

`set (CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "armv7 arm64")`

I've tried moving this around to different places in the CMakeLists, but it makes no difference and the architecture is not set as it was with the command line.

Why does the command line work, but the explicit setting in the file not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation for [CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES.html) explicitely says:

> The value of this variable should be set prior to the first *project()* or *enable_language()* command invocation because it may influence configuration of the toolchain and flags. It is intended to be set locally by the user creating a build tree.

As far as I understand, toolchain file is executed even before the first command in `CMakeLists.txt`. If this file checks the variable, you have no other choice than setting the variable from command line. Some generator-dependended code is executed at the very beginning too.

Comment: Strangely, it worked only after I moved the statement to *after* my project() call. I am not using a toolchain file. Strange, what was successful for me is opposite of the docs you quote.

Comment: Really strange. Looks like compiler detection code, which is executed at `project()`/`enable_language()` call, modifies this variable. It would be interesting to set this variable before `project()` and output (with `message()`) after it.

Comment: i set it, then call project, then have this line: `message(STATUS "archs is" ${CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES})` and it is empty, wherease it is as I've set it before `project()` so it's odd to me that my generated xcode project has different settings when I set it before `project` since it would seem `project` erases that setting

Comment: it looks like this other variable is affecting the architecture setting as well, hence all the confusion: `  set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT iphoneos)`