# CLion can't find nvcc when installed from conda

Tags: cmake, cuda, clion

I installed cuda toolkit, which includes nvcc, using the [official Nvidia conda repo](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#conda-installation).

It works when I manually invoke nvcc on terminal, but when I create a Cuda project in CLion, on startup of the project I get

```
Failed to find nvcc.

  Compiler requires the CUDA toolkit.  Please set the CUDAToolkit_ROOT
  variable.
```

Makes sense; it's not in my path, so I go to CMakeLists.txt tab in CLion and put `set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "/home/xdavidliu/.conda/envs/foo-conda-env/bin/nvcc")`. However, nothing changes; still same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to go to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deps -> CMake, then under CMake options, put

```
-DCMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER=/home/xdavidliu/.conda/envs/foo-conda-env/bin/nvcc
```

Then it worked.

Probably [related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461535/)